# SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise Compatible

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup-restoration, upgrade

We currently have SQL 2008 (non R2) installed on our development server. Our production server has SQL 2008 R2 Standard, so we would like to upgrade our development server so they are "compatible". Can I install Enterprise on the development server and have it been compatible with the production server?

AKA SQL is only future compatible. Does that mean Version to Version (2008 R2 to 2008 R2) or Version/Edition to Version/Edition (2008 R2 Enterprise to 2008 R2 Enterprise)?

Assume we are not utilizing any features that are limited to Enterprise.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can I install Enterprise on the development server and have it been compatible with the production server?"  -Yes